# Specialize type when hiding property in subclass c#

Tags: c#, oop

i need an help on a really easy question about oop .net design.

I've an abstracted class:

```
public abstract class DataExtractionMethodConfig
{
    public abstract DataExtractionMethod DataExtractionMethod { get;  }
    public object DataExtractionConfig { get; protected set; }

}
```

where DataExtractionConfig is a simple object that will be used in subclass to contains the configuration details. For example the OdbcExtractionConfig will be

```
public class OdbcExtractionConfig
{
    public string OdbcName { get; set; }
    public string BarcodeFilterExpression { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    public string SqlCommand { get; set; }
    public Enum.DatabaseServer DatabaseType { get; set; }
    public List<string> KeyColumns { get; set; }
}
```

and the derived concrete class is

```
public class OdbcDataExtractionMethod : DataExtractionMethodConfig
{
    private OdbcDataExtractionMethod(){}

    public OdbcDataExtractionMethod(OdbcExtractionConfig config)
    {
        this.DataExtractionConfig = config;
    }

    public override DataExtractionMethod DataExtractionMethod { get { return DataExtractionMethod.ODBC; } }
}
```

How can i refactor the code to have DataExtractionConfig typed and not a simple object but mantaining the capability to extend the abstract class ?

Comment: Create an abstract DataExtractionConfigBase base class that the configuration classes are derived from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i refactor the code to have DataExtractionConfig typed and not a simple object

By using Generics, but I warn you it can sometimes be a rabbit hole! Meaning that once you start down it, you get deeper and deeper, and things get more and more complex as you go.

```
public abstract class DataExtractionMethodConfig<T>
{
    public abstract DataExtractionMethod DataExtractionMethod { get;  }
    public T DataExtractionConfig { get; protected set; }
}
```

And then

```
public class OdbcDataExtractionMethod : DataExtractionMethodConfig<OdbcExtractionConfig>
{ ... }
```

Comment: Really simple! thanks but why can it be a rabbit hole?